# Unable to deploy app on android phone (reportlab problem)

Tags: python, android, kivy, reportlab, buildozer

The app that I was trying to deploy on my phone works well on my desktop PC. I deployed it on my phone using the following command:

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

When I tried to run app on my phone it crashed. Using:

```
adb logcat | grep python
```

I got the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab'

I 'solved it' by editing `buildozer.spec` file:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,reportlab
```

But, when I tried to deploy app again I got:

```
[INFO]:    Downloading reportlab
[INFO]:    -> running mkdir -p /home/pawel/PycharmPr...(and 82 more)
[INFO]:    -> directory context /home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages/reportlab
[INFO]:    -> running basename https://bitbucket.org/...(and 40 more)
[INFO]:    -> running rm c088826211ca.tar.gz                                   
[INFO]:    -> running rm -f .mark-c088826211ca.tar.gz
[INFO]:    Downloading reportlab from https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/get/c088826211ca.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 216, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 555, in build_recipes
    recipe.download_if_necessary()
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 347, in download_if_necessary
    self.download()
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 393, in download
    self.download_file(self.versioned_url, filename)
  File "/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/TwoScreens/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 208, in download_file
    urlretrieve(url, target, report_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1826, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tempfile.py", line 624, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: read of closed file
```

My understanding is that `buidozer` is trying to download `reportlab` and failed. I was thinking about downloading `reportlab` manually and place it in proper folder. Anyway, I have no idea how to that; also I am not sure if it solves my problem. Any help/hint would be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still have this issue, I had the exact same problem, unfortunately I still haven't find a better way of doing this so in the end, I simply did this:

1. Go to where you installed `reportlab`. In my case this is: `~/home/samdev/repo/venv/myproject/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.
2. In there copy the folders: `reportlab` and `reportlab.libs` into your **root** project folder, then
3. Remove `reportlab` as a dep in `buildozer.spec` `requirements`.

Now it should build no problem